# Alinhamento de elementos <pre><code> no css

Tags: css, html5

**Exemplo código sem indentação**

```
/*Exibindo trecho de código no HTML utilizando o <pre><code>*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <code>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;

&lt;h1&gt;JavaScript Functions&lt;/h1&gt;

&lt;p&gt;This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p id=&quot;demo&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;script&gt;
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2;
}
document.getElementById(&quot;demo&quot;).innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);
&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;

        </code>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

**Código Indentado:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <code>
            &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
            &lt;html&gt;
            &lt;body&gt;

            &lt;h1&gt;JavaScript Functions&lt;/h1&gt;

            &lt;p&gt;This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:&lt;/p&gt;

            &lt;p id=&quot;demo&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

            &lt;script&gt;
            function myFunction(p1, p2) {
                return p1 * p2;
            }
            document.getElementById(&quot;demo&quot;).innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);
            &lt;/script&gt;

            &lt;/body&gt;
            &lt;/html&gt;
        </code>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Dessa forma o `arquivo.html` está indentado porém ele modifica a forma de como o elemento `<pre><code>` e visualizado na pagina.

Como posso alinhar o trecho de código para esquerda sem atrapalhar a indentação do `arquivo.html`?

Comment: Atrapalhar a identação? Você quer que ele alinhe automaticamente?

Comment: Quero que o trecho de código  ele seja exibido alinhado a esquerda independente da forma que o código esta escrito dentro do <pre><code>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coloca uma classe para o `<pre>` que contenha a propriedade abaixo:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: Nossa obrigado ! nunca ia saber procurar isso kkkkk !